# Groped list in sencha touch 2.2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.2

I am using groped list. it works fine except having one problem. the list doesn't refresh until it is scrolled. I used refresh() and load() function to refresh the list but this didn't worked. Thanks in advance.

Here is the list configuration..

```
{
            id: 'teamListId',
            xtype: 'list',
            scrollable: true,
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div class="teamInfo">',
                                '<div class="teamName">{teamName}</div>',
                                '<div class="teamStatus">',
                                    '<tpl if="isMyTeam === true">',
                                        '<img src="resources/images/check.png"/>',
                                    '<tpl else>',
                                        '<img src="resources/images/add.png"/>',
                                    '</tpl>',
                                '</div>',
                            '</div>'),
            store: 'Team',
            itemCls: 'teamListItem',
            action: 'teamListItemTap',
            grouped: true,
            flex : 1
        }
```

Here is the code segment that changes the group field value of record and thereafter I am reloading the store.

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
      url: strUrl,

      params: {
      Id : Id,
      param2 :paramValue2,
      param3 : paramvalue3,
      },
      success : function(response, opts) {
      if(response.result == 'success') {
          var teamStore = Ext.getStore('Team');
          teamStore.load({
             params: {
             league_Id : leagueId,
             subscriber_email : userEmail
             }
             });
          }
      },
      failure : function(response, opts) {
          Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
          if (response.timedout) {
          Ext.Msg.alert('Timeout', 'The server timed out. Please try again later.', Ext.emptyFn());
          }
          else if (response.aborted) {
          Ext.Msg.alert('Aborted', 'Looks like you aborted the request!', Ext.emptyFn());
          }
          else {
          Ext.Msg.alert('Bad', 'Something went wrong with your request.', Ext.emptyFn());
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Need some code to help u please share a sencha fiddle if possible..

Comment: Ur using pull to refresh plugin to refresh the list/ how r u updating the list r just calling refresh to store.

Comment: I am just reloading the store..

Comment: k then before reloading sync the store and then reload should do it..

Comment: sync and reload didn't worked for me.

Comment: Hi iam sry could'nt help u yesterday little busy have u solved it..

Comment: Not having a good luck till now

Comment: have u tried this method getUpdatedRecords( ) on the store and see whether ur able to get the updated records..

Comment: I didn't used getUpdatedRecords() but I am reloading the store, the store gets reloaded but doesn't render until the list is scrolled.

Comment: K before scrolling list did u check the dom whether the list's new records are present or not..

Comment: I am not getting this problem in browser.. I am getting this only on iPhone.. and sorry but Don't know how to check the Dom value... Check this also http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?274544-Grouped-List-weirs-on-store-reload

Comment: "I am not getting this problem in browser." it means u can see the updated records without scrolling on browser..

Comment: yes... this problem comes only in iPhone

Comment: I think u have mistaken somewhere if it comes in browser it will reflect the same in safari/chrome(mobile browsers)..how ru sure that it refreshes in iphone..tell me exactly how use see this in iphone the scenario i mean..